# triangles and convex quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry

I've just finished a 5 hour long regional programming competition at my university, and there was one question in particular that had me particularly stumped. It is as follows:

> Given two parallel lines, the first one containing $N$ points and the second containing $M$ points. How many triangles and convex quadrilaterals can be formed if no line contains more than 1000 points

I'd like to know if there's some general formula for any amount of points. I'm been thinking about it but I don't even know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Do triangles and quads separately.

I'm assuming that degenerate triangles (all three verts on one line) aren't counted. So every triangle must have 2 verts on one line, and one on the other.

How many ways are there of picking 2 verts on the first line? $N(N-1)/2$. And for each of these, you can pick any vert on the other line. So for triangles like this, you have $MN(N-1)/2$. For two verts on the other line and one vert on the first, you have $NM(M-1)/2$. Total
$$
MN(N+M-2)/2
$$

A similar analysis lets you work out quads, but you have to be careful: pick two verts from the first line, IN ORDER; then pick two verts from the second line, ALSO IN ORDER. Assuming that a degenerate quad (one with three or four verts on one line) isn't allowed, you get $NM(N-1)(M-1)/4$ ways to pick a quad, I believe.

Sounds as if the problem might have needed a little more detail to indicate whether degenerate triangles/quads are allowed.